# installing windows 7 on my inspiron 1720

Tags: windows-7, dell-inspiron

My inspiron 1720 originally came with Vista, but I installed windows xp on it anyway.

It was a bit of a pain to get xp to work because of driver issues etc.

Do you guys forsee any issues if I install windows 7 on it?  i.e. will I have to go out and search for drivers or should it just work automatically :)

Comment: "It was a bit of a pain to get xp to work because of driver issues" that surprises me, as Dell offers XP drivers for this model ... but then, this might not have been the case when you bought it. i remember, Dell had to revise their policy regarding XP drivers due to "popular demand" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly save to assume that Windows 7 will work on a machine that came with Vista

Gnoupi and I both checked the Dell site: no Windows 7 specific drivers. However the Dell site also states you should give the Vista drivers a go if you can't find them.

I suspect Windows Update will also find most generic drivers. Last case resort is trying the hardware vendors, which in the case of such broadly used model shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I've just checked, no Win7 drivers on their site, only XP and Vista 32.

Comment: Great, now it looks like I edited your answer to add myself :-] I should have thought twice before correcting that typo!

Comment: Always wanted to try rollback

Answer (score 6):

If Vista runs on this computer then it will be 'flying' Windows 7, however, to be sure to be sure, run the **[Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1B544E90-7659-4BD9-9E51-2497C146AF15&displaylang=en)**.

Dell doesn't offer any Windows 7 drivers for the Inspiron 1720, so you will have to hunt them down from the part manufacturers' websites (or use the Vista drivers if you can't find any, they should work).

The Stac 92xx C Media HD Audio Vista driver works with Windows 7, depending on your GPU, you will find Windos 7 video drivers at Intel or nVidia, get the latest touchpad driver from Synaptics, the rest should be automatically detected and installed.

Edit: If you find 3 unknown (base) devices after the installation, this is your card reader. grab the Vista driver from the [Dell website](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&ServiceTag=&SystemID=INS_PNT_PM_1720&os=WLH&osl=en&catid=&impid=) (the Ricoh driver under "Chipset"), extract it (e.g. with [Unversal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract)) and install the drivers manually via the Device Manager.

Comment: +1 I like your answer better ;-)

Comment: +1 for the card reader suggestion.  Pulled my hair out on an IBM ovber this issue

Comment: yep, while checking their site i saw the ricoh driver under chipset, which rang a few bells alright :)

Answer (score -1):

just get the tool called double driver..this will do a complete backup of your installed, working drivers. Then just use those on your new Win7 install..

Comment: Transplanting drivers from WinXP to Win7 sounds like a very bad idea.